# Category with subpages links

Tags: seo

I have a website : www.mysite.com
I am trying to find out how is the best way to get better subpages , with a high Google Rank

And in this website i have categories : www.mysite.com/category
In this category i will have subpages with photos added, so there will be extra links like this  : www.mysite.com/category?page=2 ,www.site.com/category?page=3 .....

My question , is it better FOR SEO/RANKING to have all the new created pages like this ?
www.mysite.com/category/page=2 , www.mysite.com/category/page=3 ....

Thank you
Andu

Answer (score 0):

Some advices for better SEO Ranking hope can hep you:

Rewrite URLs in more friendly SEO way, for example www.mysite.com/category?CategoryName=Software can be rewritten in www.mysite.com/Software/ to do this use URL Rewrite Tool on your web server.
In your case I would design the Urls in this way
instead of

- www.mysite.com/category/page=1
- www.mysite.com/category/page=2

I would use

- www.mysite.com/NameCategory/01/
- www.mysite.com/NameCategory/02/

In this way you will gain keyword reach Urls laso more human readable.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the following structure:

domain.com/category1/post1.html

domain.com/category2/post2.html

As you increase your posts the categories will take more force if you have a good group of keywords.

Regards.

Comment: Hi andu if you find out on of our answer useful please vote up :)